# How do I fix facebook circular redirect?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I did 4 landing pages on a website http://www.getyogi.fr/ and a php script randomize the differents landing pages.

But my problem is to fix the open graph facebook.
He returns:
Could Not Follow Redirect Path - Using data from http://www.getyogi.fr/lp1/ because there was an error following the redirect path.

Here is my open graph HTML:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Le yoga en ligne">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="GET YOGi">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.getyogi.fr/">
<meta property="og:description" content="GET YOGi est un site pour pratiquer le yoga en ligne et prendre soin de vous où et quand vous voulez. Depuis votre mobile, votre tablette ou votre ordinateur, des cours HD disponible 24H/24, 7 jours /7.">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="677363099034751">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.getyogi.fr/lp1/img/yoga1.jpg">
```

Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is because of the URL you are using in your `og:url`. You say that you have a piece of PHP which randomizes a landing page and then redirects the user to that page. Here is what is happening:

1. Crawler goes to https://your-url.com/
2. Your PHP generates a landing page and redirects the crawler to https://your-url.com/landing-page-1
3. On landing-page-1 the crawler sees the `og:url` is  https://your-url.com/ which is considered the canonical URL so the crawler then goes there
4. Now we are stuck in a loop between step 2 & 3

There are a couple of options you can do here:

**Option 1:** on your landing pages have the `og:url` be the URL of the landing page the user lands on.

**Option 2:** on the main URL have your randomizing PHP script ignore requests from the Facebook crawler which has a user agent of `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message too but for a totally different reason. I resolved the error by adding OpenGraph in the language attributes (in the header)

For example:

```
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="https://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```